# JAXB Client not disconnecting when finished grabbing resource

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, client, jersey

I'm using Jersey to simply connect and grab a web resource, but after it finishes, the client doesn't "disconnect" and just hangs.

```
public String getResource() {
  Client client = Client.create(config);
  WebResource resource = client.resource(someURI);
  return resource.path("path").path("to").path("resource").accept(....).get(String.class);
}
```

If I call this method from a main, it does return the proper resource, but the program doesn't exit afterward.

Comment: In what package is your Client object??

Comment: I wonder if this is throwing an exception before hanging. Could you surround everything with a try/catch and see if it does?

Answer (score 0):

if you have now pending responses and want to free your resorce, you should use `client.destroy()`.